# worklight security - force login every 2 weeks

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

Trying to better understand security implementation options.   When using IBM Worklight, to force a user to login only every 2 weeks, what approach would you recommend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One of the options is to set two weeks timeout. 
Another is to generate some kind of token with 2w validity and use it instead of user/pass when logging in.

Answer (score 0):

2 weeks?

Sounds like you'll need to set the session timeout value in worklight.properties to be 2 weeks-long, then...

Answer (score 0):

- First I will use **Adapter-based authentication** to authenticate the user into the application: [https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/authentication-security/adapter-based-authentication/][1]
- Second, you can try to configure the **serverSessionTimeout** property in file worklight.properties to 20160 minutes(2 weeks). The serverSessionTimeout property defines client inactivity timeout, after which the session is invalidated. A session is an object stored in the server memory for each connecting device. Among other data, it stores authentication information. Active sessions are determined by the number of sessions opened versus the sessions timing out due to lack of activity. The default session timeout is 10 minutes, but it can and should be configured. Users typically set the timeout to anywhere from 5 to 10 minutes. This parameter affects the server memory consumption.
- In addition, the mobile client has a **heartbeat** property that allows the mobile client to ping the server while the app is in the foreground, so that the server session will not time out. *Note: When a mobile app has moved into the background, it no longer interacts with the server, nor sends a "heartbeat". The result is that the server session drops after the specified server session timeout.*